# Unable to get the elements from my JSON output

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm very new to python and still learning. I am making an API call to an application which returns some wonky output and I think I have managed to convert it to JSON. But when I try to access the JSON data using the Keys I get some error.

Below is what I have managed to do by myself -

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json
import re

url = 'url'

def get_FOA():
    call_to_get = requests.get(url + "data", verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, Password))
    dd = str(call_to_get.json())
    dd = dd.replace("'",'"')
    filed = json.dumps(dd)
    filed['name']
```

When I run the above code, I get the below error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:/joffscp/another.py",
>   line 26, in 
>       get_FOA()   File "D:/joffscp/another.py", line 19, in get_FOA
>       filed['name'] TypeError: string indices must be integers

When I print the 'filed' which has the JSON output, I get the below.

> "[{\"_ref\":
>   \"dhcpfailover/ZG5zLmRoY3BfZmFpbG92ZXJfYXNzb2NpYXRpb24kZnJlLg:fre\",
>   \"name\": \"fre\"}, {\"_ref\":
>   \"dhcpfailover/ZG5zLmRoY3BfZmFpbG92ZXJfYXNzb2NpYXRpb24kdGVzdC1taWNyb3NvZnQuNg:test-microsoft/10.192.32.161\",
>   \"name\": \"test-microsoft\"}, {\"_ref\":
>   \"dhcpfailover/ZG5zLmRoY3BfZmFpbG92ZXJfYXNzb2NpYXRpb24kTXNfdGVzdC42:Ms_test/10.192.32.161\",
>   \"name\": \"Ms_test\"}, {\"_ref\":
>   \"dhcpfailover/ZG5zLmRoY3BfZmFpbG92ZXJfYXNzb2NpYXRpb24kbGV3aW5kb3dzLTEwLjE5Mi4zMi4xNjEuNg:lewindows-10.192.32.161/10.192.32.161\",
>   \"name\": \"lewindows-10.192.32.161\"}]"

Answer (score 2):

`filed = json.dumps(dd)` will take an object (`dd`) and turn it into a string. That's why you get the error - `filed` is a string, and you can't do `filed['name']`.

You already have the result of the JSON as a dictionary from `call_to_get.json()`. Don't turn that into a string - and you can just do `call_to_get.json()['name']`:

```
def get_FOA():
    call_to_get = requests.get(url + "data", verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, Password))
    filed = call_to_get.json()
    return filed['name']
```

Comment: I tried this, but Python finds the 'filed" to be a list somehow. I read somewhere that .json() would produce a list I'm afraid, not sure how to proceed.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/joffscp/another.py", line 24, in <module>
    get_FOA()
  File "D:/joffscp/another.py", line 17, in get_FOA
    return filed['name']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: Oh, your json is a list of dictionaries, each of which has a `name` attribute. You'll have to loop over them to (`for x in filed: ...`) to get each one, or whatever else you need.